# Actionscript 3.0: TypeError: Error #1006: addToValue not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

I'm sure there's some dumb mistake hiding from me, but I've been at it for over 2 hours and cannot seem to find what's going wrong. Someone please help me determine what I am doing wrong, the error is in the title and the following is my relavent code.

FURTHER USEFUL DETAILS:

Exact error is the following:

TypeError: Error #1006: addToValue is not a function.
    at SimpleMenuMain/onTick()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

The game runs, but does not count score, I want the score to be counted. I have triple checked that all my instance names are correct, I really don't see anything wrong with what I've done there. Possibly I somehow could be referencing them incorrectly, but all the names used in the code ARE ON my objects inside symbols and texts...etc.

Thank you so much for your time, this has really been killing me.

P.S.---I'm following a tutorial so if I'm doing something unnecessary don't blame me! Although other comments in addition to helping me answer this conundrum are welcome =).

DOCUMENT CLASS

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class SMGDocClass extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var playScreen:SimpleMenuMain;
        public var titleScreen:TitleScreen;
        public var gameOver:GameOver;

        public function SMGDocClass() 
        {
            titleScreen = new TitleScreen();
            titleScreen.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.START,onRequestStart,false,0,true);
            titleScreen.x = 0;
            titleScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(titleScreen);

        }

        public function onStickman1Death(stickman1Event:Stickman1Event):void
        {
            var finalScore:Number = playScreen.getFinalScore();
            var finalClockTime:Number = playScreen.getFinalClockTime();

            gameOver = new GameOver();
            gameOver.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.RESTART,onRequestRestart,false,0,true);
            gameOver.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.MAINMENU,onRequestMainMenu,false,0,true);
            gameOver.x = 5;
            gameOver.y = 6;
            gameOver.setFinalScore( finalScore );
            gameOver.setFinalClockTime( finalClockTime );
            addChild(gameOver);

            playScreen = null;

        }

        public function onRequestStart( navigationEvent:NavigationEvent ):void
        {
        playScreen = new SimpleMenuMain();
        playScreen.addEventListener( Stickman1Event.DEAD, onStickman1Death,false,0,true );
        playScreen.x = 0;
        playScreen.y = 0;
        addChild( playScreen );

        titleScreen = null;
        }

        public function restartGame():void
        {
            playScreen = new SimpleMenuMain;
            playScreen.addEventListener(Stickman1Event.DEAD, onStickman1Death,false,0,true);
            playScreen.x = 0;
            playScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(playScreen);

            gameOver = null;
        }

        public function onRequestRestart(navigationEvent:NavigationEvent):void
        {
            restartGame();
        }

        public function onRequestMainMenu( navigationEvent:NavigationEvent):void
        {
            titleScreen = new TitleScreen();
            titleScreen.addEventListener(NavigationEvent.START,onRequestStart,false,0,true);
            titleScreen.x = 0;
            titleScreen.y = 0;
            addChild(titleScreen);

            removeChild(gameOver);
            gameOver = null;
        }

    }
}
```

playScreen CLASS

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class SimpleMenuMain extends MovieClip {

        public var army1:Array;
        public var enemy1:Enemy1;
        public var gameTimer:Timer;
        public var stickman1:Stickman1;

        public function SimpleMenuMain() {

            army1 = new Array();
            var newEnemy1 = new Enemy1( 100, -15 );
            army1.push(newEnemy1);
            addChild(newEnemy1);

            stickman1 = new Stickman1();
            addChild(stickman1);
            stickman1.x = mouseX;
            stickman1.y = mouseY;

            gameTimer = new Timer(25);
            gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick, false, 0, true);
            gameTimer.start();

        }

        public function onTick(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
        {
            gameClock.addToValue( 25 );
            if ( Math.random() < 0.1 )
            {
                var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 400;
                var newEnemy1:Enemy1 = new Enemy1( randomX, -15 );
                army1.push( newEnemy1 );
                addChild( newEnemy1 );
                gameScore.addToValue( 10 );
            }

            stickman1.x = mouseX;
            stickman1.y = mouseY;

            for each (var enemy1:Enemy1 in army1)
            {
                enemy1.moveDown();

                if (stickman1.hitTestObject(enemy1))
                {
                    gameTimer.stop();
                    dispatchEvent(new Stickman1Event(Stickman1Event.DEAD));
                }
            }

        }

        public function getFinalScore():Number
        {
            return gameScore.currentValue;
        }

        public function getFinalClockTime():Number
        {
            return gameClock.currentValue;
        }

    }

}
```

Counter CLASS

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Counter extends MovieClip
    {
        public var currentValue:Number;

        public function Counter()
        {
            reset();
        }

        public function addToValue( amountToAdd:Number ):void
        {
            currentValue = currentValue + amountToAdd;
            updateDisplay();
        }

        public function reset():void
        {
            currentValue = 0;
            updateDisplay();
        }

        public function updateDisplay():void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Stickman1Event CLASS

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class Stickman1Event extends Event 
    {
        public static const DEAD:String = "dead";

        public function Stickman1Event( type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false ) 
        { 
            super( type, bubbles, cancelable );

        } 

        public override function clone():Event 
        { 
            return new Stickman1Event( type, bubbles, cancelable );
        } 

        public override function toString():String 
        { 
            return formatToString( "Stickman1Event", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase" ); 
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationEvent CLASS

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class NavigationEvent extends Event 
    {
        public static const RESTART:String = "restart";
        public static const START:String = "start";
        public static const MAINMENU:String = "mainmenu";

        public function NavigationEvent( type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false ) 
        { 
            super( type, bubbles, cancelable );

        } 

        public override function clone():Event 
        { 
            return new NavigationEvent( type, bubbles, cancelable );
        }

        public override function toString():String 
        { 
            return formatToString( "NavigationEvent", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase" ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Score Class

```
package
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    public class Score extends Counter
    {
        public function Score()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function updateDisplay():void
        {
            super.updateDisplay();
            scoreDisplay.text = currentValue.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I am completely blind, you never define nor instantiate `gameScore` and `gameClock`, the two objects you are trying to call `addToValue()` on. Not sure why this isn't throwing a null-ref error, but that is definitely the issue. Those objects do not exist and therefore cannot have that method on them.

Comment: Those are both defined as instances on my main timeline....that's why it isn't throwing a full error I think....and as long as I've given them instance names I think I should be able to reference them like that just fine?

Comment: Are they instances of `Counter`? Counter has the `addToValue()` method, so they need to extend that class in order to have access to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josh has already pointed out, there is no guarantee that the gameScore and gameClock objects are actually instances of Counter.

We would need to see the code/place where you instantiate it.

Some possible options;

- gameScore and gameClock are not actual Counter instances
- you are instantiating the counter as a MovieClip, so you have added it to your stage, but you may not have hooked the Library asset and Counter class together correctly.

Can you change your Counter constructor to this and run it;

```
public function Counter()
{
    trace("i am a counter");
    reset();
}
```

... you should see the trace output twice (for gameScore and gameClock), if you are not seeing the trace output, the Counter is not being constructed, which means the gameScore and gameClock are just plain MovieClip instances.

Comment: Ahh thank you for these tips. It appears the 2nd bullet point was the problem. I somehow had created two symbols of the same thing, and I had the wrong library symbol on my game screen, the Counter class wasn't actually the one being used! Thanks again